# Get volume paths on Automator shell service

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I'm trying to make a service in Automator to run a program on my usb key (to run as a right click service).

This is the bash shell script I need to run

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/KINGSTON
fatsort -f -oa /dev/disk1s1
```

The two paths `/Volumes/KINGSTON` and `/dev/disk1s1` should be treated as variables, being evaluated by Automator.
I get the first one with "Get selected Finder elements" and I put on the shell script as $1

I.E.

```
diskutil unmount $1
```

But I don't know how to get the /dev path

Comment: Try typing `mount` in the Terminal to see if that gives you what you want = if so, you can use `do shell script` to get it.

Comment: Yes, mount on Terminal gives me "/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/KINGSTON" that's exactly what I need (but I need to split it in 2 "variables")

Comment: So, if you want the device special file for `KINGSTON`, you can do `mount | awk '/KINGSTON/{print $1}'`

Comment: This is the script

`diskutil unmount /Volumes/KINGSTON

fatsort -f -oa /dev/disk1s1`

but KINGSTON and disk1s1 should be variables

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the bigger picture, or context, of what you are actually trying to achieve, nor what `fatsort` is. Things might be clearer if you clicked `edit` underneath your question and explained the entire thing of what you are trying to do and which bits you are stuck with.